# set variable in calling object from object being called

Tags: java

In Java, how do you set variables in a calling object from the object that is being called?  I guess I could set up some kind of struct class, but can someone show me if there is a simpler way to do it, such as some modification of the pseudocode below:

```
public class Example(){  
  int thisInt;
  int thatInt;

  public static void main(String[] args){  
    Another myAnother = new Another();
  }
  setThisInt(int input){thisInt=input;}
  setThatInt(int input2){thatInt=input2;}
}

public class Another(){  
  void someFunc(){
    this.Example.setThisInt(5);//I know this syntax is wrong
    this.Example.setThatInt(2);//I know this syntax is wrong
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your reasons for doing this? I expect that there are other solution to your original problem that are in line with common Object Oriented programming practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in a reference to the object.

```
public class Another{  
  void someFunc(Example ob){
    ob.setThisInt(5);
    ob.setThatInt(2);
  }
}
```

If you're using [nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)(one class inside the other with an implied parent-child relationship), use:

```
OuterClass.this.setThisInt(5);
```

and so on.

Comment: +1 for the quick answer.  Thank you.  Impressive response time.

Comment: @CodeMed Yeah, I keep [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=newest&pagesize=30) open in a tab at all times. Really handy.